# Add an increment based on alert notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, increment, tic-tac-toe

I'm writing a TicTacToe game and I'm having trouble adding the Win Count to track how many games the X player wins and how many games the O player wins.  Right now, I have the JS code with an if statement. If alert = Winner is X, then xWinCount++ but I'm not sure this is the correct way.  Thanks for any and all help, I really appreciate it.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 header">
    <h1 class="banner">Previous Games</h1>

    <h1 class="banner">Rules</h1>

    <h1 class="banner-right">List of Wins</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 nine hidden-xs red"></div>
    <!--previous game-->

    <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs green-bg">
      <!--rules + who's turn is it -->
      <p>Classic Tic-Tac-Toe game.</br>
        </br> Match three X's or three O's in a line vertically, horizontally or diagonally to win!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs blue">
      <!-- List of wins -->
      <div class="win-chart">
        <p class="win-chart">X has won:</p>
        <p id="xWinCount" class="xWinCount win-chart">0</p>
        <p class="win-chart">time(s)</p>
        </br>
        <p class="win-chart">O has won:</p>
        <p id="oWinCount" class="xWinCount win-chart">0</p>
        <p class="win-chart">time(s)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 nine hidden-xs red"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 nine" id="board">
        <div class="col-md-4 innerNine empty borderBottom col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 innerNine empty borderBottom borderLeftAndRight col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 innerNine empty borderBottom col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 innerNine empty col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 innerNine empty borderLeftAndRight col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 innerNine empty col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 innerNine empty borderTop col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 innerNine empty borderTop borderLeftAndRight col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 innerNine empty borderTop col-xs-4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs"></div>
      <!--blue not needed -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 nine red"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="newGame" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>Restart Game </button>
        <a href=" " button id="newGame" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>Reset Scores</button></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
      <!--blue not needed -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var circleOrEx = "o"; // who gets first turn, right now circle goes first
  var isGameInProgress = true; // when the document loads, the tictactoe board is an active game
  var winningCombos = { // the game board is a series of nine square boxes, but since this is an array, the values for earch box is 0 to 8.  these values outline the winning combinations starting from each possible square on the board.  the board is writen out like this:

      // 0 | 1 | 2  
      // ---------  
      // 3 | 4 | 5
      // ---------
      // 6 | 7 | 8

    0: [ //0 is key (winning combinations starting from the top left square)
      [1, 2], //if the user enters in three of the same values across the top three squares, they win
      [3, 6], //if the user enters in three of the same values down the far left column, they win
      [4, 8]  //if the user enters in three of the same values  diagonally from the top left to bottom                       right, they win
    ],
    1: [ //(winning combinations starting from the top middle square)
      [0, 2], //if the user enters in three of the same values across the top three squares, they win
      [4, 7]  //if the user enters in three of the same values down the middle column, they win

    ],        //there are no diagonal winning combinations for values 1, 3, 5, 7 

    2: [ //(winning combinations starting from the top right square)
      [0, 1], //if the user enters in three of the same values across the top three squares, they win
      [5, 8],  //if the user enters in three of the same values down the far right column, they win
      [4, 6]   //if the user enters in three of the same values  diagonally from the top right to bottom                       left, they win
    ],
    3: [ //(winning combinations starting at the middle square on the far left column )
      [0, 6], //if the user enters in three of the same values down the far left column, they win
      [4, 5] //if the user enters in three of the same values across the middle row, they win
    ],
    4: [ //(winning combinations starting at the center square)
      [1, 8], //BUG IN THE CODE, this should not be a winning combination
      [2, 6], //if the user enters in three of the same values  diagonally from the top right to bottom                       left, they win
      [1, 7], //if the user enters in three of the same values down the middle column, they win
      [3, 5] // if the user enters in three of the same values across the middle row, they win
    ],
    5: [ //(winning combinations starting from the middle square in the far right column)
      [2, 8], //if the user enters in three of the same values down the far right column, they win
      [3, 4] // if the user enters in three of the same values across the middle row, they win
    ],
    6: [ //(winning combinations starting from the bottom left square)
      [0, 3], //if the user enters in three of the same values down the far left column, they win
      [2, 4], //if the user enters in three of the same values  diagonally from the top left to bottom                       right, they win
      [7, 8] //if the user enters in three of the same values across the bottom three squares, they win
    ],
    7: [   //(winning combinations starting from the bottom middle square)
      [1, 4],//if the user enters in three of the same values down the middle column, they win
      [6, 8] //if the user enters in three of the same values across the bottom three squares, they win
    ],
    8: [  //(winning combinations starting from the bottom right square)
      [0, 4], //if the user enters in three of the same values  diagonally from the bottom right to the top               left, they win
      [2, 5], //if the user enters in three of the same values down the far right column, they win
      [6, 7] //if the user enters in three of the same values across the bottom three squares, they win
    ]
  };

  // when the user clicks on the board, the function runs, and the game is in progress
  $("#board").find("div").on("click", function() {

    if (isGameInProgress && $(this).hasClass("empty")) { /// within the #board remove the empty class and add either an X or an O value to the square when it is is clicked
      $(this).removeClass("empty").append("<span class='" + circleOrEx + "'>" + circleOrEx + "</span"); //allows user to input X or O value in the square

      checkIfWon($(this).index(), circleOrEx); //function determines the turn cycle of the game 

      if (circleOrEx === "o") { // if O has played their turn, run code on line 68
        circleOrEx = "x"; // now it is X's turn
      } else {
        circleOrEx = "o"; // X has played their turn, now it is circle's turn
      }
    }

  });

  // once you click the button with the 'newGame' id, run the function
  $("#newGame").on("click", function() {

    var boardSquares = $("#board").find("div"); //boardSquares now becomes every div element within #board, which is each of the nine blank squares that make up the tic tac toe game
    var firstEmptyMemorySquare = $(".container").find(".nine").filter(function() { //returns a value for firstEmptyMemorySquare if the function passes these requirements place the #board within the class nine that is in the containter. (once the game clicking the refresh button, place the previous board in an empty section of the page)
      return $.trim($(this).text()) === "" && $(this).children().length === 0;
    }).not("#board").first();

    if (firstEmptyMemorySquare.length == 1) { //placing a previously played game in an EmptyMemorySquare
      firstEmptyMemorySquare.html($("#board").html());
    } else {
      $(".container").find(".nine").not("#board").empty();
      $(".container").find(".nine").first().html($("#board").html());
    }

    //deletes anything in the empty class to games that are in progress, which allows user to enter X's or O's in the boardSquares
    boardSquares.each(function() {
      $(this).addClass("empty").empty();
    })
    isGameInProgress = true;
  })

  //checks if a player won. chosenSquare is the final value in a winning combination; the possible values for the  chosenSquare parameter is [0] - [8] 
  function checkIfWon(chosenSquare) {

    var mulitArr = winningCombos[chosenSquare];
    var playerWon;

    for (var i = 0; i < mulitArr.length; i++) { //the nested loop provides the length of the multidimensional array
      playerWon = true;
      for (var j = 0; j < mulitArr[i].length; j++) { //value of j starts at zero so the user must enter three values within a winning combination.  If j initially starts at 1 user only needs to match two of the same values within a winning combination.  If j => 2 the user only needs to match one value of a winning combination (which would be any square on the board) 
        if (!$("#board").find("div").eq(mulitArr[i][j]).find("span").hasClass(circleOrEx)) { //Explain this condition
          playerWon = false;
        }
      }

      if (playerWon) { //remaining lines affect the board when a player enters a winning combination

        for (var j = 0; j < mulitArr[i].length; j++) {
          $("#board").find("div").eq(mulitArr[i][j]).find("." + circleOrEx).addClass("green"); //makes the first two inputs of the winning comination the color green
        }
        $("#board").find("div").eq(chosenSquare).find("." + circleOrEx).addClass("green"); //makes the last         input of the winning combination (chosenSquare) the color green
        alert("Winner is " + circleOrEx.toUpperCase() + "!"); //alert "Winner is X" or "Winner is O"
 var xWinCount = 0;
    var xWinCount = 0;
      if (playerWon = Ex){
          document.getElementById('xWinCount');
          var xWin = xWinCount.innerHTML;
          xWinin++;
          xWinCount.innerHTML = x-win;
          }
      else{
      document.getElementById('oWinCount');
      var oWin = oWinCount.innerHTML;
      oWin++;
      oWinCount.innerHTML = o-win;
      }
        isGameInProgress = false; //since a player has won, the game is no longer in progress
        return false; //this exits the loop
      }
    }


  }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately alert() cannot return any data.

Comment: you may also want to consider piecing together a jsfiddle. thats a fair bit of code to understand, yet the relevant bit to help debug wont be all the html and css.

Comment: @m0atz I've made a jsfiddle document, unfortunately I can't get the result section to display full screen 

https://jsfiddle.net/evdd0qv9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Watch out this line `document.getElementById('xWinCount');` is not assigned to a variable seems you want to `xWinCount = document.getElementById('xWinCount');` same for `oWinCount`

You will have the element which `innerHTML` must be holding your current score, and yeah later you can modify or increment its value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume everything works up until the checkIfWon function fires because that's quite a bit of code to siphon through.

Incrementing a win count should be fairly trivial. Looking at the code you have, I can see a couple of issues.

```
  // The first problem is your function.  You pass it 2 arguments but it only catches 1
  // The second argument is what character 'won', so it should look something like this:
  // function checkIfWon(chosenSquare, winningPlayer)
  function checkIfWon(chosenSquare)

  var xWinCount = 0;
  // playerWon is a boolean. You need to know if the player won, but also which player won.
  // You should use the variable passed in through the function parameters
  // if (winningPlayer == "x" && playerWon)
  if (playerWon = Ex){
      // document.getElementById returns an object.  
      // To grab the innerHTML attribute from an object, you can do something like this:
      // xWinCount = document.getElementById('xWinCount').innerHTML;
      document.getElementById('xWinCount');
      var xWin = xWinCount.innerHTML;

      // Assuming you get the above code working, 
      // the increment and assignment code should look something like this:
      // xWinCount++;
      // document.getElementById('xWinCount').innerHTML = xWinCount;
      xWinin++;
      xWinCount.innerHTML = x-win;
  }
```

The else statement should address the same issues I posted above.

Here's my version, using jQuery since it's a little easier and it looks like it's available based on the other code in your project. You should be able to figure out the 'else' portion from that code snippet.

```
function checkIfWon(chosenSquare, winningPlayer) {
    if (playerWon) {
        if (winningPlayer == 'x') {
            // Grab the current win count
            var xWinCount = $('#xWinCount').val();

            // Increment the count
            xWinCount++;

            // Assign the new count
            $('#xWinCount').val(xWinCount);
        }
    }
}
```